# Yii2 Gridview filtering not working

Tags: php, yii2

Can you help me out with implementing filters to GridView in Yii2? Right now, my rendered table does not respond to my actions (search GET params are not added, nothing changes if I enter a query to a filter input). Here's my code:
Controller:

```
$searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataprovider = $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->get());
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataprovider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]);
```

Model (UserSearch.php):

```
public $fullname;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['fullname'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function search($params) {
        $query = StUsers::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
           'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if(!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'fullname', $this->fullname]);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

View:

```
GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                'id',
                'fullname'
                ],
            ]);
```

Comment: `$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);`

Comment: did it. But still, if I enter some text into the input and press ENTER - nothing happens ((

Comment: Have you added that column name in searchable array in modal ?? i mean safe search rules array.

Comment: show generated query after search.

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251515/yii2-related-table-filter-and-sort) maybe it will help, it is more advanced search

Comment: I made Gii generate CRUD for me. Even now, if I put any text to filter inputs - NOTHING HAPPENS!

Comment: Open DEV window and get HTML code for any input field. Check if there are any EventListeners attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when filtering in DataView. Perhaps the problem is in the client side.
Check again if your jquery called twice on your page ( browser/source code ). 
May be your problem related with this also :
[jQuery(...).yiiGridView is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603370/jquery-yiigridview-is-not-a-function)

Comment: You should add a brief description of the solution, not only the link. Furthermore, if the question is already answered, you should flag the question as duplicated

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for a solution since 4 years have passed. But, problem is in next statement:

```
    if(!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Change it to:

```
    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly issue is **jquery.min.js**
You should referencing not more than once
Try to see if you have repeated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).